# Retrieving last 12 months data per ga:year

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I'm trying to generate data for the last 12 months in Google Sheets using the `GA` add-on but `ga:users` is not showing same figure as `GA` web because my dimension is `ga:year` which makes it break it down to adding 2016 to 2017 data.

`ga:month` would break it down too much and give the overall figure a greater difference.

Any ideas how to fix this so that I can same data as web for users?

Thanks.

Here's my configuration:
Last year Partner
core
ga:xxxxxxxxxxx
01/08/2016
31/07/2017

```
ga:users
ga:sessions
ga:bounceRate
ga:pageviews
ga:pageviewsPerSession
ga:year



HIGHER_PRECISION
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the users from the two distinct years will not match the users from the web interface. The web interface is giving you the de-duplicated number of users. 
i.e. anyone visiting the site in Nov-16 and Feb-17 is counted as one user in the web interface, while you are double counting them from your yearly output.

Comment: That's correct but is there a way to rectify this to show last 12 months just like in the web interface?